I have problem in getting users list in clerk auth
I'm trying to retrieve a list of all users who have signed up in my Next.js application. I created an API route (/users/route.ts) with a GET action to fetch the users using the Clerk client:
export const GET = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  try {
    const { data: users } = await clerkClient.users.getUserList();
    return NextResponse.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Failed to fetch users' }, { status: 500 });
  }
};

However, I'm experiencing an issue where only older users are returned in the response. The recently signed-up users are not always fetched—sometimes they appear, and other times they don't. I can see all the users in the Clerk dashboard, and I've tried restarting the server, but the problem persists. I'm not sure how to resolve this and consistently retrieve the full user list.
What did i try?
I tried to fetch the list of all users who signed up in my Next.js application by creating an API route (/users/route.ts) with a GET action using the Clerk client. My code attempts to retrieve the user list and return it as a JSON response.
What was i expecting?
I expected the API to return the complete list of all users, including both older and recently signed-up users, every time I made a request. However, the response only includes the older users, and the recent users sometimes don’t appear in the list, despite being visible in the Clerk dashboard.

If this is due to nextjs's default coaching behaviour, You'll need to revalidate your data either on demand or Time-based, i'm supposing you are using a fetch request inside a component of yours, in fetch options you can include { next: { revalidate: 0 } } to see if that's the problem.

I haven't found the solution but I don't have the issue anymore and my advice is to use clerkClient().users instead of clerkClient.users

const res = (await clerkClient()).users works
docs have const res = await clerkClient().users

const { data } =  await (await clerkClient()).users.getUserList({
  emailAddress: userIds
});

const users = data?.map(user => ({
  id: user.id,
  name: `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`,
  email: user.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress,
  avatar: user.imageUrl
}));

This code block works absolutely fine for me.



import { clerkClient } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

export async function getAllUsers() {
  const response = await clerkClient();
  const users = await response.users.getUserList();
  console.log(users);
}



